# How Can I Create a Database Accessed By windows and Android

Tags: android, database

I have been looking and searching for this whole day, so i want to create a database which can be accessed by both computer and smartphone, is there a way to do it, and how ?
Sorry For Beginner Question, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ok, the first thing you should do is to define the type of database
  that you want. You can build SQL or No-SQL database. For the most
  part I would suggest no-sql so something like MongoDB could do, but you can always do mySQL. As
  for accessing that db with anything actually, you need application
  layer around it. You see, database acts as just a huge data
  container thus it should not be used for any other logic.
- Now, lets talk about application layer. To be more precise - about posting/updating/retrieving data from db. You should research something about RESTApi or GraphQL concepts as they are used to make communication between your app and your db which is hosted on a server (I deliberately did not talk about how you can build an app because I assumed you already know this one).

**THE POINT**: The most important concept to wrap your head around is how you can access the db you make not the type or tech used to build it. (Even though this is important too)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this its creating a web service, so your app will talk to this web service, the web service will talk to your database and retrieve the results to your app (this can be done using HTTP protocol's APIs like Volley for android) and its a secure way to do it.

You can connect your application direct to your database granting external access, but this is a specif configuration according to your database (mysql, ms sql, etc.) and its **not recommended**.

You can think in the same way to the computer(s) that will access your database, except if this computer(s) is in the same network which the computer that your database is hosted in, in this last case, the program in this computer (which will access the database) can access it directly (you need to setup the database to permit  this and this setting is diferent according to your database).